# Smooth transition to screens with custom elements

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to create a transition between two screens where the second screen contains a custom element which needs to be initialized after the screen changes, as the element it depends on needs to exists. I am using tick() to let svelte create the second screen (and the select element I need).

The problem with this method of course is that since the the transition is started before the element can be initialized, svelte can't take into account the "real" height of the element after it has been initialized, only the height of the vanilla .

Here is a basic recreation of my issue: https://svelte.dev/repl/a3283cd4fe3a434496f09ac40195dcee

As you can see, the screen will "jump" to the correct height after the transition is over.

Is there a correct way to achieve a smooth transition in this situation?

Comment: Include relevant code *in the question*, do not just link somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing the select via [an action](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-action) seems to be working fine

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fbbaf17bfc554b2e83ee3661eb145110?version=4.2.1)

```
<svelte:head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.2.2/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.2.2/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    import { slide } from 'svelte/transition';

    let mainScreen = "one";
    
    const animals = [
        { value: "dog", name: "Dog" },
        { value: "cat", name: "Cat" },
        { value: "lion", name: "Lion" },
        { value: "tiger", name: "Tiger" },
        { value: "elephant", name: "Elephant" },
        { value: "giraffe", name: "Giraffe" },
        { value: "zebra", name: "Zebra" },
        { value: "penguin", name: "Penguin" },
        { value: "panda", name: "Panda" },
        { value: "koala", name: "Koala" },
    ];

    async function toggleScreen () {
        mainScreen = mainScreen === "one" ? "two" : "one";
    }

    function initTomSelect(selectElem) {
        const select = new TomSelect(selectElem, {
            labelField: 'name',
            items: animals.map(x => x.value),
            options: animals,
        });

        return {
            destroy() {
                // the node has been removed from the DOM
                select.destroy()
            }
        };
    }
</script>

{#if mainScreen === "one"}
    <div transition:slide class="screen">
        <div class="padder">
            <button on:click={toggleScreen}>other screen</button>
        </div>
    </div>
{:else if mainScreen === "two"}
    <div transition:slide class="screen">
        <div>
            <select use:initTomSelect 
                style="width:100px;" 
                multiple
                >
            </select>
        </div>
        <button on:click={toggleScreen}>other screen</button>
    </div>
{/if}


<style>
    .screen{
        background:#eee;
    }

    .padder{
        padding:200px;
    }
</style>
```